# Brackets used in C and their purposes

Tags: c

I'm sorry if this has been asked before, but I'm a beginner to C and I was wondering if someone could help explain the use of the `()` brackets in the following code.

I took it from an online tutorial and it runs fine, but there's one part of it I don't understand.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int age;
    printf("Please enter the age");
    scanf("%d", &age);
    if (age > 18 /*condition */ ) {
       printf("You may enter the club");
       if (age < 21)
       {
        printf("The age is greater than 18 but less than 21");

    }    else
        (printf("The age is greater than 18 and greater than 21"));


} else if (age == 18)
{
    printf("The age is equal to 18");
}
else {
    printf("The age is not greater than 18");
    }

return 0;
}
```

From what I've gathered the round brackets are used to contain the conditions of an if statement, and the curly brackets are used to state the operation which follows that condition.
Except for the nested else condition in bold, where the else statement is followed by a round brackets enclosing the print command.

Could anyone explain why this is so?

Comment: These are completely redundant.

Comment: Those would likely be considered wrong. Those should be curly braces.

Comment: They work because `printf()` function call returns an `int` - it is an expression; you can wrap an expression into `()` parentheses for grouping, just like `(5 + 3)`. All in all, better to find another tutorial.

Comment: The parentheses after the else are in a weird style. They are used in the order of operations sense, except there is only one operation and it is redundant

Comment: i suspect its a typo that is actually harmless so never got fixed, its certainly not normal

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Round brackets `()` (as well as curly brackets `{}`) may appear in several different contexts, serving different roles.

Curly brackets in `if` are mostly required in cases when you need to combine several statements on into one *compound* statement to serve as a true or false branch of `if`. In your case, for example, each branch of `if (age < 21)` is just one statement already, which means that curly brackets in its branches are not really necessary. You can just write that `if` as

```
if (age < 21)
  printf("The age is greater than 18 but less than 21");
else
  printf("The age is greater than 18 and greater than 21");
```

At the same time true branch of `if (age > 18)` contains multiple statements, which is why you need curly brackets there.

Meanwhile, round brackets that surround `if` condition is just a syntactic element of `if` statement - the grammar requires a pair of round brackets around `if` condition, just like it requires round brackets in `for`, `while`, function call and other syntactic constructs.

But round brackets can also be used in a completely different role: in expressions, where their primary purpose is to group operators with their operands, as in `(2 + 2) * (5 - 3)`. However, in expressions you are free to use redundant brackets, e.g. you can write `(((2))) + (3)` instead of `2 + 3`. Or you can add superfluous brackets around the entire expression, e.g. `(((2 + 3)))` instead of `(2 + 3)` and so on.

This is exactly what you observe in your example. Your

```
printf("The age is greater than 18 and greater than 21");
```

is just an expression statement, i.e. a statement consisting of a single expression. That expression is a call to `printf`. If you so desire, you can enclose that call into any number of redundant round brackets

```
(((printf("The age is greater than 18 and greater than 21"))));
```

with no change in its meaning.

The combination of these two factors: the fact that you don't really need `{}` around that `printf`, and the fact that you can put as many `()` around that `printf` as you want, creates an illusion that in case of that `printf` a pair of `{}` was somehow *replaced* by a pair `()`. In reality, these are two completely unrelated actions.

In any case, it is just a syntactic curiouslty, not something with any practical value. How it happend in the code from the tutorial - anyone's guess.

Answer (score 2):

The `else` condition should also be followed by curly brackets, denoting which statements should be executed as part of the `else` clause. If there is a single statement in the `else` clause, then these braces **may** be omitted, although some consider this poor coding style. In this case, the curly braces have been omitted. Additionally, a redundant pair of normal parentheses have been added, which make the code more confusing.

I would highly recommend replacing these parentheses with curly braces, even though the code is technically correct. Additionally, the code should be written with a consistent indentation pattern. It makes the logical flow of the program much easier to follow:

```
int main()
{
    int age;
    printf("Please enter the age");
    scanf("%d", &age);

    if (age > 18 /*condition */ ) {
        printf("You may enter the club");
        if (age < 21) {
            printf("The age is greater than 18 but less than 21");
        }
        else {
           printf("The age is greater than 18 and greater than 21");
        }

    }
    else if (age == 18) {
        printf("The age is equal to 18");
    }
    else {
        printf("The age is not greater than 18");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I believe the OP didn't write this code, they got it from an online tutorial.

Comment: Just noticed this. Fixed

Comment: I'm afraid I think the assertions in this answer are less than helpful to a rank newbie.  I think it would be more useful to observe that both the `if` and the `else` branches *always* take a single statement, but that it can be a compound statement composed of a sequence of zero or more statements enclosed in curly braces.  This exhibits the language's consistency, rather than couching it in terms of rules and exceptions.  In that context, however, going on to recommend using always the compound-statement form would be fine.

Comment: Productivity tip: The mis-aligned `if else` etc. code implies manual formatting.  Find an auto-formatter that is close to your group's style and work with it.  Leave formating details to automation.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's a typo. Any expression, including one in brackets, can be introduced at any time. Braces here make more sense and would be consistent with the rest of the code if formatted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a typo: there's no legitimate programming reason to use those parentheses. But note that it compiles just fine because it does nothing: (x) is the same as x, so enclosing the printf(...) in more parentheses is acceptable but changes nothing.

Answer (score 0):

It's legal but absolutely useless, courtesy of flexible syntax system of C.

This expression is legal:

```
int i =  printf("The age is greater than 18 and greater than 21");
```

can be this

```
int i =  (printf("The age is greater than 18 and greater than 21"));
```

and can be this

```
(printf("The age is greater than 18 and greater than 21"));
```

It woudn't be legal if printf was returning void.
 Consider it to be an expression that was wrapped in oarenthesis, but it's value wasn't used. It's possibly a typo, that passed because code is still legal.

Answer (score 0):

An expression, terminated by a semi-colon `;`, becomes a statement.

`printf` is a function returning an `int`.

So the result of `printf` is an expression (so `printf()` is an expression).

An expression enclosed in braces is an expression.

So `printf()`enclosed in braces and followed by a semi-colon is a statement.

A statement must follow `else`. So there is no syntactical problem here.

Answer (score 0):

You'll be familiar with the common use of parenthesis in mathematical expressions.

for example, `3*(1+1)` will evaluate to 6 because the add takes place before the multiply and the multiplication uses that value on the right hand side.

The thing you may not know is that function calls in C are expressions. So even though nothing is done with the return value of the `printf()` it's legal (though eccentric to put it in redundant parenthesis.

So the following makes sense:

```
  int count=printf("Hello");
```

Assuming no error `count` will be initialized as 5 (the number of characters printed). But it's just as valid (though redundant) to write:

```
  int count=(printf("Hello"));
```

But the assignment doesn't affect the syntax and the following are legal and equivalent.

```
printf("Hello");
(printf("Hello"));
```