# Are a series of nested if statements within a for loop collectively classified as a single statement?

Tags: c, for-loop, if-statement, scope

Consider a segment of code that is written as follows:

```
for (expr1a ; expr2a; expr3a) 
  if (expr 2a)
    if (expr 3a)
      if (expr 4a)
        .
        .
        .
          if (expr na)
            statement_1;
```

How exactly does the compiler interpret this chunk? Is it all, collectively, one statement? Or, perhaps, more specifically, is it one statement embedded within one statement, embedded within one statement...etc. I get no errors when I compile codes that take on this structure, so I assume that interpretation is somewhat correct.

I ask this question because in my book *C Programming: A Modern Approach*, `for` statements are described  as having the form: `for (expr1 ; expr2 ; expr3) statement` - note the *singular* nature of `statement` (i.e. **not** `statements`).

And `if` statements are described as having the form: `if ( expr ) statement` - note the singular nature of `statement`.

However, if this is the case, then I imagine a singular introduction of **another statement** (`statement_2`) **anywhere**, even if it is the null statement `;` immediately changes the interpretation. For example, if we have the code:

```
for (expr1a ; expr1b; expr1c) 
  if (expr2a)
    if (expr3a)
      if (expr4a)
        if (expr5a)
          statement_1;
```

and then changed it to:

```
for (expr1a ; expr1b; expr1c) 
  if (expr2a)
    if (expr3a)
      statement_2; /* <------ */
      if (expr4a)
        if (expr5a)
          statement_1;
```

This is actually now interpreted as:

```
for (expr1a ; expr1b; expr1c) 
  if (expr2a)
    if (expr3a)
      statement_2;

if (expr4a)
  if (expr5a)
    statement_1;
```

Is this right?

Thanks!

Comment: Your understanding is right.

Comment: Rather than worry about this, use braces even for single line statements. It is the best and most bug free way to go because nothing will end up mysteriously broken when lines are added later.

Comment: You might wanna check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45510552/brackets-used-in-c-and-their-purposes) which talks about usage of brackets.

Comment: `if` and `for` and `while` and `switch` and so on... are statements that have statements inside them.

Comment: Or another reason for braces: https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2014/02/24/anatomy-of-a-goto-fail-apples-ssl-bug-explained-plus-an-unofficial-patch/ (Goto fail)

Comment: You are simply asking whether one box that contains other boxes is a box. Yes, it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> in my book C Programming: A Modern Approach, for statements are
> described as having the form: for (expr1 ; expr2 ; expr3) statement -
> note the singular nature of statement (i.e. not statements).

You can write for example

```
for (expr1a ; expr2a; expr3a)
{
    statements;
}
```

And the for loop has one compound statement. So the definition of the for statement with one statement is correct.

In this code snippet

```
for (expr1a ; expr2a; expr3a) 
  if (expr 2a)
    if (expr 3a)
      if (expr 4a)
        .
        .
        .
          if (expr na)
            statement_1;
```

the for loop has one statement

```
  if (expr 2a)
```

that in turn also has one statement

```
    if (expr 3a)
```

and so on.

This code snippet

```
for (expr1a ; expr1b; expr1c) 
  if (expr2a)
    if (expr3a)
      statement_2; /* <------ */
      if (expr4a)
        if (expr5a)
          statement_1;
```

Is equivalent to

```
for (expr1a ; expr1b; expr1c) 
  if (expr2a)
    if (expr3a)
      statement_2; /* <------ */

if (expr4a)
    if (expr5a)
      statement_1;
```

That is the for loop has one statement

```
  if (expr2a)
```

that in turn has one statement

```
    if (expr3a)
```

and this if statement has one statement

```
      statement_2; /* <------ */
```

After the for loop there is followed another if statement

```
if (expr4a)
    if (expr5a)
      statement_1;
```

I will provide a more interesting construction.

Usually the do-while statement is written like

```
do
{
    statement;
} while( condition );
```

This do-while statement contains one statement - compound statement that in turn contains one statement.

But you may rewrite this do-while statement the following way

```
do statement; while ( condition );
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

size_t count_digits( int n )
{
    const int Base = 10;
    
    size_t count = 0;
    
    do ++count; while ( n /= Base );
    
    return count;
}

int main(void) 
{
    int n = 12345;
    
    printf( "The number %d contains %zu digits.\n", n, count_digits( n ) );
    
    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
The number 12345 contains 5 digits.
```

Though of course it would be more readable to write at least like

```
do { ++count; } while ( n /= Base );
```

Because this record

```
do ++count; while ( n /= Base );
```

looks like two separate statements

```
do ++count; 
while ( n /= Base );
```

follow each other.